# Hide/unhide specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to create a code that allows a button to hide specific cells (e.g. (B10:B15) + C17 + C19 + (D10:D18)) when pressed and then have the reappear when pressed again? Alternatively another button for the reapearing can be accepted.

Comment: you cannot hide single cell. but you can hide entire row or column that contains that cell

Comment: alternatively you can change font color of that Cell to White to make it invisible and then black to make it visible again

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide a single cell. But if you want to hide/unhide e.g. a number of columns using a shortcut key you can do as follows:

1. In the `View` toolbar, click `Macros`, then `Record Macro...`.
2. Enter a key, under shortcut key (`Ctrl + ...`). [Let's assume you put 'h'] Then press OK.
3. Hide the columns you want to hide (or anything you want to happen by pressing the shortcut key).
4. Goto `View` toolbar, click `Macros`, then `Stop Recording`.

Now when you press the defined shortcut key (e.g. Ctrl+h), the desired columns will hide.

You can follow the same steps to define a different shortcut key for unhiding.

If you want to make some single cells (kind of) invisible, you can do that by changing the font color to match the background color. Again you can use the same steps mentioned above to create a shortcut key for that.